# How to get my Mac OS X terminal to control gunplot properly?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gunplot on mac os x (Yosemite). I can plot data, but I can't do a lot of customization:
commands like: set tics "", or rotate by ... don't work.

Do you think it's a problem from the installation or terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: Which gnuplot output terminal?

Comment: @Christoph I use AquaTerm

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that, I don't have a mac for testing. Type `test` in the gnuplot command window to see, if rotated text is supported by the terminal. `set tics ""` is wrong syntax, maybe you meant `set tics format ""`. You could also try `wxt` or `qt` as terminals, depending on your gnuplot version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have yosemite too. I suggest you use the x11 terminal.
Write:

```
set term x11 enhanced
```

Comment: It works!
but the figure is static, it doesn't rotate